# Matrix for mirroring a point across a plane

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I wonder how I can get the matrix for mirroring a point across a the plane given by 
$$4x-y+z=0$$
I also need to make a picture of all the vectors that's used.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Hint. Let $P$ be a point in $\mathbb{R}$. Then reflected point $Q$ with respect to the plane $4x-y+z=0$ can be obtained by subtracting two times the projection of $P$ onto the vector $(4,-1,1)$ (which is orthogonal to the given plane).

Comment: Thanks Robert, i get it now.